# Pagination with Ajax filtering give response 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress, pagination, filtering, categories

I use pagination on custom posts type and ajax filtering. Without choosing category, it works has it should be. After clicking category, pagination appear but next/prev link is like: [www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/page/2](http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/page/2) and give blank page with "0". IDK what should be in 'base', now is what i take from other answer, but I don't understand it good, and it doesn`t work.

function.php:

```
function filter_ajax() {

$category = $_POST['category'];
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'post_type'         => 'casestudies',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'orderby'           => 'post_date',
        'tax_query' => array(
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'ID',
        'terms' => $category,
    )
),
]);

if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();

  $response .=  get_template_part('/modules/ajax/case-studies');

endwhile;

echo '<div class="pagination">';
$total_pages = $ajaxposts->max_num_pages;

if ($total_pages > 1) {

$current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
$fallback_base = str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) );
$base = isset( $_POST[ 'base' ] ) ? trailingslashit( $_POST[ 'base' ] ) . '%_%' : $fallback_base;

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $current_page,
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('«'),
        'next_text'    => __('»'),
    ));
}

}
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_postdata();
exit;
die;
```

}

ajax-filtering.js:

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var category = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: { action: 'filter', category: category },
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                $('.js-filter main').html(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.warn(result);
            }
        });

    });
});adsds})(jQuery);
```

and part of this page, where posts are displayed:

```
<div class="js-filter-form">
           <ul name="categories" class="js-filter-select">
           <?php
              $cat_args = array(
              'order'   => 'DESC',
              );

              $categories = get_categories($cat_args);
              ?>
             
              <?php
              foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
              
              
              <li class="js-filter-item"><a href="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>"><?= $cat->name; ?></a></li>
              
              <?php endforeach; ?>
           </ul>

        </div>
     </div>

     <main class="home-case-list cases-full-list">
        <?php 
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                 
        $args = array(
           'numberposts'       => -1,
           'posts_per_page'  => 6,
           'paged'           => $paged,
           'post_type'         => 'casestudies',
           'post_status'     => 'publish',
           'order'             => 'DESC',
           'orderby'           => 'post_date'
           );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

           if($query->have_posts()) {
              while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

              $response .=  get_template_part('/modules/ajax/case-studies');

              endwhile;
           
              echo '<div class="pagination">';
              
                 $total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

                 if ($total_pages > 1){

                 $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

                 echo paginate_links(array(
                    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                    'format' => '/page/%#%',
                    'current' => $current_page,
                    'total' => $total_pages,
                    'prev_text'    => __('«'),
                    'next_text'    => __('»'),
                 ));
                 }   
           }
           echo '</div>';
           wp_reset_postdata();
     ?>

     </main>
```

Comment: Did you find answer on your question ?